# passing lambda expression with input and output

Tags: c#, lambda

I've been trying for long but can't seem to figure out the solution.

A function that takes a string and returns an object of type `IVehicle`.

**Method Signature**

```
public class Car: IVehicle 
{
    public static IVehicle GetCar(Func<string, IVehicle> lambda)
    {
    //...
    }
```

**Method Call**

```
Car.GetCar("lambo" => new Car("lambo"));
```

**Question:**

What changes can I do to my call to be compatible with the method signature?

Targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: Note that `x => new Car(x)` is shorthand for `(string x) => new Car(x)`, makes it easier to see why you can't substitute `"lambo"` for `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetCar` needs a method which takes a `string` and returns a type which implements `IVehicle`.

Therefore, you need to provide a method like below:

```
Car.GetCar(x => new Car(x));
```

Here is a longer version, without lambda, to explain what is going on there:

```
Car.GetCar(CallThisMethod);

// See the signature of this method: it takes a string and returns IVehicle
public static IVehicle CallThisMethod(string someString)
{
    return new Car();
}
```

Comment: can you please test it with actual string in place, isn't your answer same as my attempt?

Comment: `Car.GetCar("lambo" => new Car("lambo"));` isn't the same?

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper You can't have a string on the left side of the '=>'operator, you're just defining a function, you're defining the parameter's name not the parameter itself. Writing "lambo"=> whatever is like trying to write a function with signature IVehicle GetCar("lambo") instead of IVhehicle GetCar(string x), it makes no sense, you're mixing defining the function with calling it

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper no it is not the same. See my edited answer to achieve the same thing without lambda.

Answer (score 0):

As @odingYoshi suggested you need to change it so that the `Func` takes in a variable and uses that one:

```
Car.GetCar(x => new Car(x));
```

If you need to pass in the variable `x`, you could hardcode it in the `Func`:

```
Car.GetCar(x => new Car("lambo"));
```

However, if you need to do that you probably shouldn't be using a `Func` at all:

```
public static IVehicle GetCar(string carName)
{
    IVehicle car =  new Car(carName);

    //Anything extra
}
```

Another alternative is to pass the string into the method as well:

```
public static IVehicle GetCar(Func<string, IVehicle> lambda, string carName)
{
    IVehicle car =  lambda(carName);

    //Anything extra
}
```